# Why can't an identifier start with a number?

Tags: rust

I have a file named `1_add.rs`, and I tried to add it into the `lib.rs`. Yet, I got the following error during compilation.

```
error: expected identifier, found `1_add`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:5
  |
1 | mod 1_add;
  |     ^^^^^ expected identifier
```

It seems the identifier that starts with a digit is invalid. But why would Rust has this restriction? Is there any workaround if I want to indicate the sequence of different rust files (for managing the exercise files).

Comment: Rust's identifier rules mostly follow the precedent set by C, which states that identifiers are sequences of alphanumerics and underscores and cannot start with a number. Back then, it was probably a trick to make parsing code easier (if we see a number, we can definitely say we're looking at a literal, not a variable, etc.). Nowadays, it's mostly a historical thing. There are languages (Lisp dialects come to mind immediately) where such identifiers are allowed, but most C-derived languages disallow it on principle

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: ah, lisps, where you write ASTs directly :) code is data is code. Fun times.

Comment: The language's lexer grammar supports literals like `123_u32`. It would be difficult to distinguish such literals from variables beginning numeric characters. That's just a minor consideration and not really a primary reason, but pertinent. I believe `_1_add` would be a valid var/function identifier;  but why not just make it `add_1`..

Comment: @Todd because of lexicographic ordering, I'm assuming.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's in the way lexers are designed to split text into tokens to pass on to the parser. The answers posted have good examples where the lexer would require special handling for things like `1_2`.

Comment: @Todd: I was answering the "why not just make it `add_1`", actually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case (you want to name the files like `1_foo.rs`) you can write

```
#[path="1_foo.rs"]
mod mod_1_foo;
```

Allowing identifies to start with digits can conflict with type annotations.  E.g.

```rust
let foo = 1_u32;
```

sets to type to `u32`.  It would be confusing when `1_u256` means another variable.

Answer (score 6):

> But why would Rust has this restriction?

Not only rust, but most every language I've written a line of code in has this restriction as well.

Food for thought:

```
let a = 1_2;
```

Is `1_2` a variable name or is it a literal for value `12`? What if variable `1_2` does not exist now, but you add it later, does this token stop being a number literal?

While rust compiler probably *could* make it work, it's not worth all the confusion, IMHO.

Comment: @R.yan: use a valid prefix. An underscore, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69210936/125816). Or a proper word, `task_1_add.rs`, `task_2_quicksort.rs`.

Comment: Great point about the confusion during declaring variables.

Comment: Also `1e10` for example

Answer (score 3):

Allowing identifiers to start with a digit would caus conflicts with many other token types. Here are a few examples:

- `1e1` is a floating point number.
- `0x0` is a hexadecimal integer.
- `8u8` is an integer with explicit type annotation.

Most importantly, though, I believe allowing identifiers starting with digit would hurt readability. Currently everything starting with a digit is some kind of number, which in my opinion helps when reading code.

An incomplete list of programming languages not allowing identifiers to start with a digit: Python, Java, JavaScript, C#, Ruby, C, C++, Pascal. I can't think of a language that *does* allow this (which most likely does exist).

Comment: For example [`1+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Rust identifiers are based on [Unicode® Standard Annex #31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/)
(see [The Rust RFC Book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2457-non-ascii-idents.html#reference-level-explanation)), which standardizes some common rules for identifiers in programming languages. It might make it easier to parse text that could otherwise be ambiguous, like `1e10`?

Answer (score 1):

"*Why?*" cannot be reasoned here but by historical tales, the rules are as such. You cannot play against them.

If you urgently want to start your identifiers with a digit, at least for human readers, prepend an underscore like this: `_1_add`.

*Note: To make sure that sorting works well, use also leading zeroes as many as appropriate (`_001_add` if you expect more than 99 files).*

Comment: Some ref on RFC book: https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2457-non-ascii-idents.html

Comment: You could also make argument that it conflicts with `1u8` notation.